# JS: Get all months from specific date until today (also using moment.js)

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Let say I have a specific date such as: `21-03-2013` and I would like to get the month I use: `moment("04-03-2013","DD-MM-YYYY").format('MMMM');` which gives me March.

Now for the date today I use `moment().format('MM');` which gives me october.

How do I get all the months in-between in names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will also work with a longer period (> 1 year) - if necessary

```
function getDates(startDate /*moment.js date object*/) {
    nowNormalized = moment().startOf("month"), /* the first of current month */
    startDateNormalized = startDate.clone().startOf("month").add("M", 1), /* the first of startDate + 1 Month - as it was asked for the months in between startDate and now */
    months = [];

    /* .isBefore() as it was asked for the months in between startDate and now */
    while (startDateNormalized.isBefore(nowNormalized)) {
        months.push(startDateNormalized.format("MMMM"));
        startDateNormalized.add("M", 1);
    }

    return months;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ztvr/1/)

**Update**
As suggested by Matt in the comments, I'm now using `.clone()` and `.startOf("month")` instead of creating the normalized clones on my own

Comment: Good answer.  But probably need to check for `isSame` also, or use `<=` comparison.

Comment: also you could use `.clone().startOf('month')` to build `nowNormalized` and `startDateNormalized`, but that's just a minor optimization.

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks for the hint with `.clone()` and `.startOf()` - I haven't heard of them yet. These are my first steps with moment.js :)

Answer (score 1):

This function take a string of the format "DD-MM-YYYY" and return an array with all the months from that date to current

```
function getMonths(startDate){

    var startMonth = parseInt(startDate.split('-')[1], 10),
        endMonth = parseInt(moment().format('M'), 10),
        monthArray = [];

    if( startMonth < 1 ) return [];

    for( var i = startMonth; i != endMonth; i++ ){
        if( i > 12 ) i = 1;
        monthArray.push( moment(i, "M").format("MMMM") );
    }

    monthArray.push(moment().format('MMMM'));

    return monthArray;
}

getMonths("04-03-2013");
```

Comment: Always specify a radix when using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Parameters) - which in this case should be `parseInt(..., 10)`. Otherwise a date like `01-08-2013` or `01-09-2013` may result in a wrong `startMonth`